# How to find whether it is possible for each vertex of a graph to have a different degree?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I want to prove whether it is possible for a graph to have different degrees for each vertex. I think that it can be possible with an example, but I can't prove it with mathematics.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Consider a graph with zero or one vertex.

Comment: Please notice that the singular is "vertex" and the plural is "vertices".  I changed "vertice" to "vertex" in the question.

Comment: i was confused when i wrote it and i am not a native english speaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every simple graph with at least two vertices has at least two vertices of the same degree.

http://www.student.math.uwaterloo.ca/~math239/winter2008/t7sol.pdf

http://www.mymathforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=20418

This was among the first result when searching for ["two vertices" "same degree"](http://www.google.com/#q=%22two+vertices%22+%22same+degree%22). You can also find many [books](http://books.google.com/books?q=%22two+vertices%22+%22same+degree%22&hl=en&ie=UTF-8) containing this claim.

Comment: i googled it but didint find anything..however this seems true for vertices that do not have loop.

Answer (score 12):

If you are talking of simple graphs then clearly in any connected component containing n(>1) vertices the n vertex degrees will have degrees among the numbers $\{1,2,3\cdots n-1\}$ and so by the pigeonhole principle at least 2 vertices will have the same degree. The conclusion is false if we consider graphs with loops or with multiple edges.
[image]

Comment: thank you ,this was the example i was thinking of!

Comment: For completeness - if there is no connected component with more than 1 vertices, than all connected components have exactly 1 vertex, so all vertices have degree 0, and if n > 1 then there will be at least two with equal degree.