# Proving the number of degrees in a simple graph (Graph theory)

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that in a simple graph with at least two vertices
there must be two vertices that have the same degree.

What i tried

Proving by contradiction

Suppose that no two vertex have the same degree then the lowest possible degree will be $1+2+3+...n=n(n+1)/2$. While we know that for a graph with $n$ vertex, then the maximum possible degree of each vertex is $n-1$ thus the maximum possible degree for the graph is $n(n-1)$ thus we must have $n(n+1)/2\le n(n-1)$, but if we work out the inequality, we know that this isnt true for $n=2$ thus a contradiction. contradiction. Is my prove correct and also is there a direct way to prove this. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: You do not prove that the only way to construct a graph where each vertex has a different degree is by placing loops at every vertex of the graph. You have to elaborate on that in your proof.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71724/how-to-find-whether-it-is-possible-for-each-vertex-of-a-graph-to-have-a-differen

Comment: I just edited my solutions. Is that correct now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the degrees be $d_1$, $d_2$, $\cdots$, $d_n$ in non-decreasing order, where $n$ is the number of vertices in the graph. Since it is a simple graph, $d_i \leq n - 1$. If no vertices has the same degree, then we have $d_1 = 0$, $d_2 = 1$, $\cdots$, $d_n = n- 1$. Then there is a vertex $u$ whose degree is $n - 1$, which means that $u$ is adjacent to all other vertices in the graph, which is a contradiction to the fact there is an isolated vertex ($d_1 = 0$).

Comment: I thought of another way to prove it. Suppose that no two vertex have the same degree then the lowest possible degree will be $1+2+3+...n=(n+1)/2$. While we know that for a graph with $n$ vertex, then the maximum possible degree of each vertex is $n-1$ thus the maximum possible degree for the graph is $n(n-1)$ thus we must have $(n+1)/2\le n(n-1)$, but if we work out the inequality, we know that this isnt true for all $n$ thus a contradiction. Is this proof correct.?

Comment: @yswong What does it mean by "the lowest possible degree" please?

Comment: That means the smallest possible degree the graph can have

Comment: @yswong Then you should first prove that $(n + 1) / 2$ indeed is the lowest possible degree. Note that $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$ instead of $\frac{n+1}{2}$.